# Creating Android Tab Layout in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm attempting to make my first Android app and as I understand it, you only create a new activity if it's absolutely required. I have been trying to find a way of creating a tab layout inside of a fragment. Is this possible? I have found many methods of creating a tab layout where there is a fragment per tab but not of actually creating a tab layout inside the fragment. I created a mockup of what I am attempting to do.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you have your `TabLayout` as an `Activity`, not within a `Fragment`. Each tab is a `Fragment`, so if you made the `TabLayout` a `Fragment`, you'd have nested Fragments and a glorious mess of attempting to communicate between them...

Comment: Do you mean I should create a new activity for the tabbed layout? Because I don't need tabs in the main activity.

Comment: Have more than one activity -- the "main activity" which asks for user input as above, and then the tabbed activity.

Comment: [have a look](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)